# Setting up a JDBC Connection in Crystal XI R2 to MS SQL 2005

Tags: jdbc, crystal-reports-xi

I am seeking some assitance in setting up a connection to a MSQ SQL 2005 server in Crystal Reports R2.

I have the sqljdbc4.jar driver installed, and I can connect to the database perfectly within CR4E ( Crystal Reports for Eclipse).

I am guessing it is something to do with the setup of the CRConfig.XML file.

I have added a reference to the MS SQl driver in the file, and put in the same server setup as used in CR4E.

### I receive the error:

### Crystal Reports

Invalid Argument provided.
Details: Java Server startup failure.  Please verify the PATH (JDK), CLASSPATH and IORFileLocation properties in the CRConfig.xml file. In addition, please verify you are using JDK 1.4.

I cannot find any logs to further identify the problem.

eg:

```
<DataDriverCommon>
<JavaDir>"C:\Program Files\Business Objects\j2sdk1.4.2_08\bin"</JavaDir>
<Classpath>C:\Program Files\Common Files\Business Objects\3.5\java/lib/crlovmanifest.jar;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Business Objects\3.5\java/lib/CRLOVExternal.jar;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Business Objects\3.5\java/lib/CRDBJavaServerCommon.jar;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Business Objects\3.5\java/lib/CRDBJavaServer.jar;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Business Objects\3.5\java/lib/CRDBJDBCServer.jar;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Business Objects\3.5\java/lib/CRDBXMLServer.jar;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Business Objects\3.5\java/lib/CRDBJavaBeansServer.jar;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Business Objects\3.5\java/lib/external/CRDBXMLExternal.jar;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Business Objects\3.5\java/lib/external/log4j.jar;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Business Objects\3.5\java/lib/cecore.jar;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Business Objects\3.5\java/lib/celib.jar;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Business Objects\3.5\java/lib/ebus405.jar;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Business Objects\3.5\java/lib/corbaidl.jar;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Business Objects\3.5\java/lib/external/freessl201.jar;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Business Objects\3.5\java/lib/external/asn1.jar;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Business Objects\3.5\java/lib/external/certj.jar;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Business Objects\3.5\java/lib/external/jsafe.jar;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Business Objects\3.5\java/lib/external/sslj.jar;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQl Server JDBC Driver\sqljdbc_2.0\enu\sqljdbc4.jar;${CLASSPATH}</Classpath>
<IORFileLocation>${TEMP}</IORFileLocation>
<JavaServerTimeout>1800</JavaServerTimeout>
<JavaServerStartupTimeout>30</JavaServerStartupTimeout>
<JVMMaxHeap>64000000</JVMMaxHeap>
<JVMMinHeap>32000000</JVMMinHeap>
<NumberOfThreads>100</NumberOfThreads>
```

```
<CacheRowSetSize>100</CacheRowSetSize>
<JDBCURL>jdbc:sqlserver://myserver:1433;databaseName=mydb</JDBCURL>
<JDBCClassName>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</JDBCClassName>
<JDBCUserName>sr0</JDBCUserName>
<JNDIURL></JNDIURL>
<JNDIConnectionFactory></JNDIConnectionFactory>
<JNDIInitContext>/</JNDIInitContext>
<JNDIUserName>weblogic</JNDIUserName>
```

Comment: Not sure if it is related to the error but you are trying to use a JDBC 4.0 (probably Java 6 compiled) library on Java 1.4.2 (JDBC 3.0). This will fail due to class-file difference, not to mention potential dependency problems.

Answer (score 0):

To setup `JDBC` connection in Crystal XI , You need to have Jdk installed in your machine.

Check and verify you have Jdk 1.4.2 installed. If not Download and install the Java Development Kit (JDK) Version 1.4 (J2SE)or later.

Change javaDir to new installed java dir.

For example:

```
<JavaDir>C:\j2sdk1.4.2_06\bin</JavaDir>
```

and

chek you have permission to write on Temp direcotry. In some OS , temp dir is read only.

```
<IORFileLocation>${TEMP}</IORFileLocation>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working.

I believe the error was related to the string containing the location of the MS SQL driver in the classpath directive.

Enclosing it in quotes work.

eg:

;"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQl Server JDBC Driver\sqljdbc_2.0\enu\sqljdbc4.jar";